# Team Foundation Server - Customer Feedback Security

Tags: tfs

I am trying to find away of allowing customers to provide feedback without giving them access to the web interface of TFS. Is this possible? We are currently using TFS 2013

What I want to do is have a group of users who can receive feedback requests via e-mail and provide feedback via the feedback client. However I do not want them to be able to view any of the work items, test cases, builds or code. Essentially I want the users to be able to use the feedback client and have no access to anything else.

I have tried setting this up using the TFS roles security and restricting the firewall to the server, but I have not managed to achieve what I want.

How can I get this to work? It seems like it would be something that many people would use?

Answer (score 0):

Yes - you need to configure them as Work Item Only users.

When they access the website they will only have access to create and view their own work items. Then give them 'create test plan' permission (don't ask) and they should be able to use the feedback tool to provide feedback but see no other options.

There is however no way to restrict the work item types that they can create. I usualy handles this by creating a template url (create a new wit and fill out stuff now click the template button) and putting that on a portal they u